# How to retain page state when selecting language in Multi Language Implementation using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, multilingual

I am using the following controller method to store the selected language and return to the Home page when users changes the selected language.

Is there a way I can redirect to the same page which the user is viewing right now with a change in display language instead of redirecting to Home Page.

```html
public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
        {
            string test = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            // Validate input
            culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);
            // Save culture in a cookie
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
            if (cookie != null)
                cookie.Value = culture;   // update cookie value
            else
            {
                cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
                cookie.Value = culture;
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            }
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: You can use `Request.UrlReferrer` and redirect to that. Or pass the current url when calling the SetCulture and use that to redirect it to

Comment: Typically you have a 2nd `string returnUrl` parameter in your method. (using `Request.UrlReferrer` will be `null` if the user navigated to the method via the address bar)